# Проиграть музыку онлайн через AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: xcode, аудио, ios, objective-c

Подскажите, как асинхронно (в потоке) воспроизводить аудио? Допустим, у меня есть список с URL.mp3 в TableView. Пример на туториал или же свой вариант, буду благодарен.

Comment: Ну же, никто не знает?

Answer (score 1):

Дождитесь загрузки файла. `-dataWithContentsOfURL` загружает файл полностью и для потокового воспроизведения не подходит.

Comment: Подскажите, как асинхронно выводить? Допустим у меня есть список с URL mp3 в TableView. Пример на туториал, или же свой вариант, буду благодарен.